# I don't see any Dashlets

Tags: dashboard, settings, dashlet

I just installed CiviCRM.
Now I wanted to input a Dashlet into the Dashboard.

But when i click on Configure Your Dashboard  it shows nothing.
I also created a report with the option make available in dashboard.
Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Example]

Comment: check the console.
Right click> inspect.
Click on the console tab

Comment: Gives this reaction:
Uncaught TypeError: ((m.event.special[e.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || e.handler).apply is not a function

Comment: @YossiCrm any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Dashlet problems can arise when you have the wrong settings in either

- Cleanup Caches and Update Paths (Administer - System Settings - Cleanup Caches and Update Paths)
- Resource URLs (Administer - System Settings - Resource URLs )

Differences can be as small as http vs https and with or without www.